# Sap Fiori OData nested expand

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm having a problem with the OData expansion, specifically I have 3 entities A, B, C with relations of the following type.
B-> A (N-0)
B-> C (N-0)
In the master-detail I would like to start from A and arrive at C.
A-> B-> C.

A is connected by a Navigation Properties in the gateway with B, the same is true for C to B.
B obviously has the Navigation Properties for both A and C.

In the master-detail view I have A->B but I need some data from C, how do I reach them?

Thanks.

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: "I need some data from C" is quite a vague description. What have you tried already in code? Are you creating a freestyle UI5 app? Or generating the app with Fiori elements + tools? We need much more information and details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the exact question is all about but if you are talking about multi-level expansion of OData then you can follow [OData Expand](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#expand) system query. OData supports both multilevel e.g. `$expand=First/Second` and also multiple e.g. `$expand=One,Two`

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your contribution! In case of an unclear question, please consider flagging the question and asking for more details rather than answering.

Comment: Understood. Will do that from next time.